# Can my units walk through my own toxic gas?

Tags: frozen-synapse-2

The Toxic Gas Grenade unit creates a persistent (for a while) area of effect that instantly takes down any enemy who wanders into it.  I've used it a couple times to zone out doorways and windows, but am wondering if it's safe for my units to walk through the gas zone to get inside.

For example, in this scenario below.  Do I need to wait for the gas to dissipate to enter?

[image: Gas Zone]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The gas affects your own units also**. This is mentioned in this guide as well :

https://gameplay.tips/guides/2966-frozen-synapse-2.html

*How to use: Gas lingers after each shot, so do not send your own units into your gas.*

Hope this helped